# Parse.com query with relation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Im try to run this query in parse.com, But Everyone not working.

I have 2 tables, One for Promote and second for Archive.

So, I need to fetch all rows in Promote table where is not in archive table.

Like this 
`SELECT * FROM promote WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT promoteID FROM archive WHERE user=userID)`.

promoteID in archive is Pointer to objectId in Promote Table.

any help Please?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this....

```
PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Archive"];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[innerQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Promote"];
[query whereKey:@"id" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *records, NSError *error) {
    if (error) return;
    for (PFObject *record in records) {
        // .....

       }
}];
```